Count the most recent consecutive non-blank columns in a row

I need to count the most recent consecutive non-blank cells in a specific row. For example, in the picture attached, it would be 1 since the newest week had a letter in it but the week preceding it did not.
This formula needs to be editable to include new weeks added to the end.

You want to count the max, the newest string of non blanks, ... Basically why 2 and not 1.

Please [edit] to clarify if you are looking for the max of consecutive values or the most recent number of consecutive values etc.

Sorry yes I am looking for the most recent number of consecutive values

I missed that first pass but have now updated my formulas to reflect it.

If the most recent week is blank but the previous week is not, should the result be 0?

Here's one answer:
=COLUMNS(O51:R51)-IFNA(XMATCH(,O51:R51,0,-1),0)

breaking it down:
COLUMNS(): gets the total number of columns in the "search" array
-: substracts the total number of columns from the ifna(xmatch()) (below)
IFNA(): what number to use if the xmatch errors
XMATCH(): finds the first empty cell in reverse order (the -1 parameter) 
note wrapping with LET would allow only one range to be updated instead of two.



New Reduce Approach inspired by The God of Biscuits' Web Apps answer to "Formula to calculate the sum of consecutive 0's and -1's"
All approaches assume that if the most recent week is blank then streak=0

REDUCE Approach
=REDUCE(,INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK(O51:R51))), LAMBDA(a,v, (a+1)*v))

TEXTJOIN/TEXSPLIT
=IFERROR(TAKE( LEN( TEXTSPLIT( TEXTJOIN(,,ISBLANK(O2:Z2)/1),1,,1)),1,-1),"")

TEXTJOIN/TEXSPLIT Multi-Row
=BYROW(O2:Z50, LAMBDA(r, IFERROR(
   TAKE( LEN( TEXTSPLIT( TEXTJOIN(,,ISBLANK(r)/1),1,,1)),1,-1),"")))

